# Launch WinPhone7 app in emulator programmatically (for automated testing)

Tags: automated-tests, windows-phone-7

I'm trying to find a way to launch WP7 applications in the emulator as part of an automated test system.  I've tried running XapDeploy.exe from the commandline with a xap specified, no luck there (was worth a shot, right?).

I can just terminate the emulator process after a certain amount of time... if only I could launch it.  Anybody know if there's a way?

Comment: Are you doing an UI based automated testing? If so, can you share details of how you're doing this.

Comment: I'm not doing any automated UI testing.  Luckily for me, the thing I'm testing sends messages to a web server, so I can just automatically confirm that those messages are getting sent.  Sorry.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Justin Angel has written a really detailed post on automating interaction with the emultor for testing. It includes details for remotely writing to isolated storage whihc may be useful if you need data on the device/emulator as part of your testing.

http://justinangel.net/WindowsPhone7EmulatorAutomation

Answer (score 1):

It seems you can launch the emulator [using XDE.exe](http://geekswithblogs.net/cwilliams/archive/2010/08/03/141171.aspx)