# How do I write automated tests for the UI of a Windows Phone 7 application?

Tags: testing, automated-tests, windows-phone-7

It is hard enough to drive a normal app var it’s UI, however when the app is not running on your development platform it is even harder.

So what tools will help me test the UI of a Windows Phone 7 application?

See also "[Are there any issues I should know about with unit test of Windows 7 Phone code?"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3831893/are-there-any-issues-i-should-know-about-with-unit-test-of-windows-7-phone-code)

Comment: What tools are you using for UI testing outside WP7?

Comment: @Matt, in the past I have used tools like AutomatedQA

Comment: Any updates to this question, like what does people use in 2019 for automated test for UI

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Expensify's (confusingly named) [Windows Phone Test Framework](https://github.com/Expensify/WindowsPhoneTestFramework) supports UI automation. I've yet to use it on a project, but it looks promising.

Comment: Note, when you post an identical answer on different questions, it raises a system flag (which is likely why your answer got attention from a moderator). It was probably deleted because it is basically a 'link answer', though I don't see how you could elaborate more beyond describing what seems promising.

Comment: @Tim - Thanks for the heads up. Unfortunately in this case, this question was the target of my "possible duplicate" cleanup so the other answer would've been the more appropriate delete. I'll keep the duplicate thing in mind for future reference.

Comment: @RichardSzalay, Does Expensify (Windows Phone Test Framework) work for Windows Phone 8 as well?

Comment: @defactodeity no it doesn't. You will need to implement it separately

Answer (score 2):

I've not seen anyone release any tooling for this yet.

If you're going to try and write something yourself, you should have a look at [this post on emulator automation and testing](http://justinangel.net/WindowsPhone7EmulatorAutomation).

X-Ref with question [3806477](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3806477/launch-winphone7-app-in-emulator-programmatically-for-automated-testing)

Answer (score 0):

Expensify is definitely an option. Other than that there is [Experitest](http://experitest.com/microsoft-announcing-the-ability-to-test-windows-phone-8-applications-with-seetest-from-experitest-2/). But Expensify does not support Windows Phone 8 and is terribly flakey after making changes to support windows phone 8.