# Are there any issues I should know about with unit test of Windows 7 Phone code?

Tags: unit-testing, windows-phone-7

I am assuming that as the code is standard C#, I can just use nUnit, TestDriven.net etc.

Have I missed something?

What “traps” have other people hit trying to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are talking about testing C# code in a Silverlight-based project, then there are some steps that need to be taken in order to use frameworks such as nUnit. The C# code in a Silverlight project will compile against the Silverlight framework binaries, so the binaries for nUnit won't work as-is since they are compiled against the standard .NET framework.

If you want to use nUnit, you can setup a regular C# class library and reference your Silverlight C# files into this project. You want to add them as a link, which is detailed [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9f4t9t92%28VS.80%29.aspx). From personal experience, this can get a little crazy because your file is linked in two places and the ability to link over the files are limited (if your Silverlight C# code references any Silverlight-specific binaries, you cannot perform this linking trick).

The other option is to use the Silverlight Unit Test Framework, the binaries for which can be found [here](http://www.jeff.wilcox.name/2010/05/sl3-utf-bits/). This works much like the Silverlight unit tester in the Silverlight Toolkit, except that it runs on the phone as a phone app.

Answer (score 1):

Have you looked at the [Silverlight Unit Testing Framework](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/silverlightut) which is now part of the [Silverlight Toolkit](http://silverlight.codeplex.com/)?

It's not been ported as part of the WP7 toolkit but some people have reported some success in using it anyway.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest [WP7-CI](http://wp7ci.codeplex.com/). I have had success with it, and it's the only thing I could find so far that works with Asynchronous unit tests, if you'll ever need them.

See also my question:

[Is there a wp7 mango unit test runner alternative to NUnit that supports the [Asynchronous] meta tag?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7343251/is-there-a-wp7-mango-unit-test-runner-alternative-to-nunit-that-supports-the-asy)