# Is there a wp7 mango unit test runner alternative to NUnit that supports the [Asynchronous] meta tag?

Tags: c#, unit-testing, windows-phone-7

I'm using the NUnit runner from http://www.jeff.wilcox.name/2011/06/updated-ut-mango-bits/, which is great, but it does not support [Asynchronous] testing (supported by regular silverlight unit tests).

Is there any runner that run these unit tests as an app on the wp7 mango emulator or device?

This is related to my previous question: [How can I get HttpWebRequest to behave as synchronously as possible?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7297748/how-can-i-get-httpwebrequest-to-behave-as-synchronously-as-possible)

Thanks!
swine

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I made a fork of the unit testing framework for just this purpose. It adds an MSBuild task that can be run from the command line.

You can find it on Codeplex: [WP7-CI](http://wp7ci.codeplex.com/)

Comment: You again! After ignoring my chat discussion thread, now you reply to my new question. Hehe ok cool I will check this out.

Comment: Forgive me but I am new to this whole Nugget thing. I have downloaded and installed NuGet and have found the WP7-CI package. Do I install this package into my WP7 app's project? Or should I create an empty WP7 app for unit testing and install it there? The instructions on your codeplex page are unclear. Thanks.

Comment: @swinefeaster - I'm quite new to the chat thing (it's a new feature), so I forget to check it. On topic, create an empty WP7 app that will contain your unit tests and install the package into that.