# WP7 - Is there any Functional testing, UI testing Automation tool for Windows Phone 7?

Tags: windows-phone-7, emulation

apart from Unit testing on WP7, is there any other tools to perform black box test, i.e functional & regresstion test automation tool for Windows Phone 7 ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I write automated tests for the UI of a Windows Phone 7 application?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3831854/how-do-i-write-automated-tests-for-the-ui-of-a-windows-phone-7-application)