# Simulate user input with Windows Phone 7 Emulator

Tags: windows-phone-7, automated-tests, integration-testing, emulation

I've seen examples of using the [Microsoft.Smartdevice.Connectivity.dll library to deploy WP7 applications](http://justinangel.net/#BlogPost=WindowsPhone7EmulatorAutomation) to the emulator.

Is it possible to then automate user input to the device as well to perform UI testing of the application running in the emulator?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I write automated tests for the UI of a Windows Phone 7 application?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3831854/how-do-i-write-automated-tests-for-the-ui-of-a-windows-phone-7-application)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The emulator doesn't include support for this.

However, if you were using a UI test automation tool you may be able to simulate the clicks/UI interaction from a script runnign on the host PC.

I've never used a UI automation test tool with a VM/emulator but that's currently the only option available to you.

Unless you have a very complicated application it may be quicker and easier to test the UI manually though as a tool wouldn't be able to query the state of the app running in the emulator and so would only have limited usage.